# Intellij Idea Rider 2017.1 Xamarin Android Run Error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, macos-sierra, rider

I am using Intellij Idea rider to develop xamarin projects. Everything worked normally since 2 day ago when a strange error started to appear when trying to run the app in android emulator. I get this strange error :    Error running Android Default: Unexpected schema version 3

In the emulators section of the android project run config i see 0 emulators. I have 5 emulators eligible for running the app. Everything is ok with the emulators because i can run the android app using Visual Studio for Mac. I am using Mac OS Sierra. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, a path to Xamarin Android SDK has changed to a wrong one for some reason. You could check this in Settings: "Rider | Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Android". If it is ok, I would contact Rider support team.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Rider. Fixed in Rider 2018.2 (EAP)
https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000540970-Error-running-Android-Default-Unexpected-schema-version-3